Counting transitions between sticks and stones configurations for extended objects
Suppose that we have a circle around which $L$ buckets are arranged. We have $k$ balls to distribute among the buckets and each bucket can contain at most one ball. Given a configuration of the balls, we characterize the configuration by the number of non-adjacent clusters of occupied buckets it contains.
Now fix three integers, $N_{1}, N_{2}, q\in\left[1,k-1\right]$. My task is to count pairs of configurations where the first has $N_{1}$ clusters, the second has $N_{2}$ clusters and the two configurations are related by $q$ non-overlapping swaps. Here, by a swap, I mean moving a ball from an occupied to an unoccupied bucket.
In a recent post I asked how to count the number of configurations with a fixed number of clusters and this community was very helpful. Unfortunately, I'm totally stuck on this problem even with the assistance I've gotten so far. I could write what I've tried but it would be little more than spelling out particular cases which are probably useless. Any suggestions about how to formalize this problem would be very welcome.
